# Trying to display previous days records with multiple records in a row in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display records from my mysql database for the previous three days, but only if the records are multiple in a row. So **show all the records for the last three days, but only if they are the same in those three days**

For example, in my database I have records that look like this:

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+ 
| id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| ts     | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| server | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| status | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

So, I have records that look like:

```
+----+---------------------+------------+----------+
| id | ts                  | server     | status   |
+----+---------------------+------------+----------+
| 1 | 2014-12-13 09:25:41 | test_host1  | new-file |
| 2 | 2014-12-14 09:25:41 | test_host1  | new-file |
| 3 | 2014-12-14 09:25:41 | test_host2  | new-file |
| 4 | 2014-12-15 09:25:41 | test_host1  | new-file |
| 5 | 2014-12-15 09:25:41 | test_host3  | new-file |
+-------+---------------------+----------+---------+
12799 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I have a query I wrote, that will display the last three days, but it display all of the servers:

```
select * from table WHERE ts > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND DATE(ts) <> DATE(NOW());
```

I only want the servers that only occur sequentially every day. So my psuedocode would be:

```
select * from table from the last three days where server has a record in all three days
```

I don't want to select servers where the server only shows up for one of the days.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I'm partly there, just need help with the last piece.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Find the servers that appear in all three days using aggregation:

```
select server
from table
where ts > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND DATE(ts) <> DATE(NOW())
group by server
having count(distinct date(ts)) = 3;
```

Then join these back in to get the original records:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select server
      from table
      where ts > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND DATE(ts) <> DATE(NOW())
      group by server
      having count(distinct date(ts)) = 3
     ) s
     on t.server = s.server
where ts > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND DATE(ts) <> DATE(NOW());
```

Comment: That's it! I have a lot to learn about SQL, and I'm learning.